German and American Driver's License
I'm from New York and got a NY DL. I'm staying 2 years in Germany, for a job opportunity. I already checked, that I have 6 month to get a German License, before my NY one isn't valid there anymore.
My question is, what happens with my American License, when I get a German one. Can I have both at the same time? Do I need to destroy my American Licence? What's gonna happen when I move back home?

I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't continue to be valid in NY (and other US states) until the expiration date.

@Barmar Getting a license in Canada will cancel your US license due to agreements and information sharing through AAMVA. All states have laws that you are allowed one license, the relevant question is does a German license count, and does Germany notify NY?

If your new employer often employs Americans, they may have someone with answers to this. If you're a US citizen, you remain a resident of your last city/town for voting purposes. You should get professional advise on other residence questions like taxes and driving.


My question is, what happens with my American License, when I get a German one.

This will depend on what agreements exists. Either it will be returned to the issuer or retained.
Since New York is not listed in Annex 11, assume there is no agreement.
If retained, up to a period of 3 years, it can later be returned if you surrender the domestic driving licence.

Can I have both at the same time?

No, the domestic driving licence will only be issued if you surrender the other driving licence.

Do I need to destroy my American Licence?

No (see above)

What's gonna happen when I move back home?

If retained, you can recieve the old one back.
If sent back, the DMV should be aware that their original driving licence was exchanged. Since an EU driving licence will contain, in Field 12, the original driving licence number (70.number.country_code) that should help in getting back your original driving licence.


§31 Erteilung einer Fahrerlaubnis an Inhaber einer Fahrerlaubnis aus einem Staat außerhalb des Abkommens über den Europäischen Wirtschaftsraum
...
(4) Auf einem auf Grund des Absatzes 1 Satz 1 ausgestellten Führerschein ist zu vermerken, dass der Erteilung der Fahrerlaubnis eine Fahrerlaubnis zugrunde gelegen hat, die nicht in einem Mitgliedstaat der Europäischen Union oder einem anderen Vertragsstaat des Abkommens über den Europäischen Wirtschaftsraum ausgestellt worden war. Der auf Grund des Absatzes 1 oder 2 ausgestellte Führerschein ist nur gegen Abgabe des ausländischen Führerscheins auszuhändigen. Die Fahrerlaubnisbehörde sendet ihn über das Kraftfahrt-Bundesamt an die Stelle zurück, die ihn ausgestellt hat, wenn mit dem betreffenden Staat eine entsprechende Vereinbarung besteht. In den anderen Fällen nimmt sie den Führerschein in Verwahrung. Er darf nur gegen Abgabe des auf seiner Grundlage ausgestellten inländischen Führerscheins wieder ausgehändigt werden. In begründeten Fällen kann die Fahrerlaubnisbehörde davon absehen, den ausländischen Führerschein in Verwahrung zu nehmen oder ihn an die ausländische Stelle zurückzuschicken. Verwahrte Führerscheine können nach drei Jahren vernichtet werden.

Driving Licence Regulation (FeV)
§31 Issuing a driving licence to the holder of a driving licence from a state outside the Agreement on the European Economic Area
...
(4) A driving licence issued on the basis of paragraph 1 sentence 1 must be marked to indicate that the driving licence was issued on the basis of a driving licence that was not issued in a member state of the European Union or another contracting state to the Agreement on the European Economic Area. The driving licence issued on the basis of paragraph 1 or 2 may only be issued against surrender of the foreign driving licence. The driving licence authority sends it back to the office that issued it via the Federal Motor Transport Authority if an agreement to this effect exists with the state in question. In other cases, it takes the driving licence into custody. It may only be returned against surrender of the domestic driving licence issued on its basis. In justified cases, the driving licence authority may refrain from taking the foreign driving licence into custody or sending it back to the foreign office. Driving licenses held in custody may be destroyed after three years.



Sources:

§ 31 FeV - Fahrerlaubnis-Verordnung (German only)

Staaten der Anlage 11 FeV

New York is not listed







My question is, what happens with my American License

Usually, you will want to get it exchanged once in Germany, but in your case, New York state doesn't have an accord for exchange, therefore you must pass all the tests as a new driver.

A U.S. license holder requiring a German license must contact a local German driving school which will provide information on the necessary paperwork and register the applicant for testing. Applicants do not need to take theoretical or behind-the-wheel lessons. However, driving schools recommend that applicants take one or two driving lessons in order to become acquainted with the skills to be tested. Total costs (without driving lessons) may average as much as EUR 425 for license holders from states with no reciprocal agreement with Germany.


I don't think this answers the question. They already know that they have to get a new license from Germany. The question is what happens to the NY license.

@Barmar, it's implied that since they have to pass all tests as a new driver their possession of a New York license is irrelevant, and need not be disclosed. Therefore, they may be able to keep it for use upon their return to the states if they intend to re-visit before it expires, but that is the question that has yet to be answered...  (so I guess I talked myself into agreeing with you!)  ;)

@MichaelHall actually I need to disclose the possession of my NY licence, because it will relieve me from the mandatory lessons (you need 15h + 15h theory and driving) and let me do the exams (theory and driving) immediately.

@Spamomane There are books available with all the questions that could come up in the theoretical test, usually organised as 30 actual tests. Go through these tests until you can pass them all, and then take the real test.

You surrender your NY driver’s licence
If you cease to reside in NY (or any other state), you no longer have a right to hold a driver’s licence from that state. There are exceptions, including for students, so check with the DMV.
You can drive in NY (or any other state) on your German licence when you visit providing its in English or you have a certified English translation or International Driving Permit.
When you return to NY permanently, you have 30 days to obtain a NY licence and surrender your German one.
I don’t know if you have to take the tests again in NY, but you do in Germany.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
